# How can I sort a multilevel BOM?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a Bill of Materials that looks like this inside of it

[image]

But for various reasons my ERP will only allow me to export the BOM as an .xlsx that looks like this

[image]

Where each member item is tied to the member item above. These means when I make a pivot table and try to find the member items of just my product, it'll only give me Assembly 1 and 3 and then I have to do another pivot table to find 1 and 3 and so forth. Some of my BOM's are 6 levels deep and making a table for each sub assembly is not ideal. Anyone have any ideas of how to handle this? My thoughts are to use something like pandas and script it out, but I wasn't sure if there was a method inside Excel that I was missing that might cover this. My end goal is to recreate something like the first picture, although the nesting isn't necessary.

Comment: I don't know of any built-in functions that would do this in Excel, but it would be trivial to do in VBA.

Comment: I'm guessing a recursive function that calls searches for member items and returns them?

Comment: That would work, or if they are all sorted as in your example (all level 1's appear in the beginning) a simple for loop would work also.

Comment: What are you trying to do with these BOMs? Are you attempting to use them for pdf drawing navigation or where-used searches?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a table as below in Ms Access.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBi2j.png)

Then make a Query as below
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCDVv.png)

You will get a result like this.
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SERff.png)

And copy this data and paste it into excel.
Make some rules in excel, and you will get the result you wanted to.